# How to setup a stereo camera with ignition?

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

Do you have any example of SDF file with stereo cameras ?

Thx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28148/how-to-setup-a-stereo-camera-with-ignition-?/) by [Clement](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/84310/clement/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thank you for your answers.
I was rather looking for how to define a stereo camera (not how to visualize it), but the answer was interesting.

The old way of adding stereo cameras in Gazebo classic was to:

- attach a sensor to the **camera_link**
- set the sensor type to **multicamera**
- define two cameras in this sensor using the **<< camera >>** tag
- add a plugin to the sensor
- explicitly set the baseline in the plugin using the **<< hack_baseline >>** tag

Here is an example of stereo camera for Gazebo classic:

```
<gazebo reference="camera_link">
    <sensor type="multicamera" name="stereo_camera">
      <update_rate>10.0</update_rate>
      <always_on>true</always_on>

      <camera name="left">
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>1024</width>
          <height>1024</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.02</near>
          <far>300</far>
        </clip>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.0</stddev>
        </noise>
        <distortion>
          <k1>0.0</k1>
          <k2>0.0</k2>
          <k3>0.0</k3>
          <p1>0.0</p1>
          <p2>0.0</p2>
          <center>0.5 0.5</center>
        </distortion>
      </camera>

      <camera name="right">
        <pose>0 -0.12 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>1024</width>
          <height>1024</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.02</near>
          <far>300</far>
        </clip>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.0</stddev>
        </noise>
        <distortion>
          <k1>0.0</k1>
          <k2>0.0</k2>
          <k3>0.0</k3>
          <p1>0.0</p1>
          <p2>0.0</p2>
          <center>0.5 0.5</center>
        </distortion>
      </camera>

      <plugin name="stereo_camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <ros>
          <namespace></namespace>
          <argument>image_raw:=image_raw</argument>
          <argument>camera_info:=camera_info</argument>
        </ros>

        <camera_name>stereo_camera</camera_name>
        <frame_name>camera_link_optical</frame_name>
        <hack_baseline>0.12</hack_baseline>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
```

With Ignition, it is a little bit different. You have to:

- attach a sensor to the **camera_link** for each camera
- set the sensor type to **camera**
- make them publish at the same rate (see https://gazebosim.org/docs/citadel/comparison#sensors)
- add a sensor plugin to the model/robot
- the baseline is set automatically thanks to the cameras pose (see https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/3b6c0f2a0bc71c5ff391852615609deec3c03674/src/systems/sensors/Sensors.cc#L746-L750)

Here is an example of stereo camera for Gazebo Ignition:

```
  </gazebo>
    <plugin name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Sensors" filename="libignition-gazebo-sensors-system.so"> </plugin>
  </gazebo>

 <gazebo reference="camera_link">
<sensor type="camera" name="right">
  <update_rate>10.0</update_rate>
  <always_on>true</always_on>
  <ignition_frame_id>camera_link_optical</ignition_frame_id>
  <pose>0 -0.12 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <topic>stereo_camera/right/image_raw</topic>
  <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
  <image>
      <width>1024</width>
      <height>1024</height>
      <format>R8G8B8</format>
  </image>
  <clip>
      <near>0.02</near>
      <far>300</far>
  </clip>
</sensor>
  <sensor type="camera" name="left">
  <topic>stereo_camera/left/image_raw</topic>
  <update_rate>10.0</update_rate>
  <always_on>true</always_on>
  <ignition_frame_id>camera_link_optical</ignition_frame_id>
  <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
  <image>
      <width>1024</width>
      <height>1024</height>
      <format>R8G8B8</format>
  </image>
  <clip>
      <near>0.02</near>
      <far>300</far>
  </clip>
</sensor>
</gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [Clement](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/84310/clement/) with karma: 3 on 2022-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2022-05-27**:
I'm not sure exactly what is this on ignition. It doesn't look like ignition sdf file to me. Ign doesn't use `<gazebo>`. If I remember right, classic uses it.

Are you sure you are using ignition?

**Comment by [Clement](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/84310/clement/) on 2022-06-09**:
Actually, I'm using URDF, and you can use the  tag inside URDF to define the Ignition plugins to link to your robot frames.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can first take a look at the sensors that are supported by [sdformat](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.9&elem=sensor). There you can find "camera", "depth_camera" and "multicamera".
In the following example I am using "camera" and "depth_camera" to replicate the stereo camera functionality.
I am not aware if "multicamera" is supported by ign gazebo and how you would use it, maybe someone else can add some more information about that.

```
<sdf version='1.8'>
<world name='auv'>
<scene>
  <sky>
    <clouds>
      <speed>12</speed>
    </clouds>
  </sky>
  <shadows>1</shadows>
  <fog>
    <color>0.05 0.2 0.2 1.0</color>
    <type>linear</type>
    <density>0.1</density>
    <start>1</start>
    <end>4</end>
  </fog>
  <ambient>0 1 1 1</ambient>
  <background>0 0.7 0.8 1</background>
  <shadows>1</shadows>
</scene>
<physics name='1ms' type='ode'>
  <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
  <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
  <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
</physics>
<plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::Physics' filename='ignition-gazebo-physics-system'/>
<plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::UserCommands' filename='ignition-gazebo-user-commands-system'/>
<plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::SceneBroadcaster' filename='ignition-gazebo-scene-broadcaster-system'/>
<plugin name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Sensors" filename="ignition-gazebo-sensors-system">
  <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
</plugin>

<gui>
  <plugin filename="GzScene3D" name="3D View">
    <ignition-gui>
      <title>3D View</title>
      <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
      <property type="string" key="state">docked</property>
    </ignition-gui>

    <engine>ogre2</engine>
    <scene>scene</scene>
    <ambient_light>0.4 0.4 0.4</ambient_light>
    <background_color>0.8 0.8 0.8</background_color>
    <camera_pose>0 1 1 0 0.5 -1.57</camera_pose>
  </plugin>

  <plugin filename="WorldControl" name="World control">
    <ignition-gui>
      <title>World control</title>
      <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
      <property type="bool" key="resizable">false</property>
      <property type="double" key="height">72</property>
      <property type="double" key="width">121</property>
      <property type="double" key="z">1</property>

      <property type="string" key="state">floating</property>
      <anchors target="3D View">
        <line own="left" target="left"/>
        <line own="bottom" target="bottom"/>
      </anchors>
    </ignition-gui>

    <play_pause>true</play_pause>
    <step>true</step>
    <start_paused>true</start_paused>
  </plugin>

  <!-- World statistics -->
  <plugin filename="WorldStats" name="World stats">
    <ignition-gui>
      <title>World stats</title>
      <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
      <property type="bool" key="resizable">false</property>
      <property type="double" key="height">110</property>
      <property type="double" key="width">290</property>
      <property type="double" key="z">1</property>

      <property type="string" key="state">floating</property>
      <anchors target="3D View">
        <line own="right" target="right"/>
        <line own="bottom" target="bottom"/>
      </anchors>
    </ignition-gui>

    <sim_time>true</sim_time>
    <real_time>true</real_time>
    <real_time_factor>true</real_time_factor>
    <iterations>true</iterations>
  </plugin>

  <plugin filename="ImageDisplay" name="front_depth_camera">
    <topic>/world/auv/model/auv/link/front_depth_camera/sensor/front_depth_camera/depth_image</topic>
    <topic_picker>0</topic_picker>
    <ignition-gui>
      <title>front depth camera</title>
      <property key="state" type="string">floating</property>
      <property type="double" key="height">300</property>
      <property type="double" key="width">300</property>
      <property type="double" key="x">1</property>
      <property type="double" key="y">1</property>
      <property type="double" key="z">1</property>
    </ignition-gui>
  </plugin>
  <plugin filename="ImageDisplay" name="front_camera">
    <topic>/world/auv/model/auv/link/front_camera/sensor/front_camera/image</topic>
    <topic_picker>0</topic_picker>
    <ignition-gui>
      <title>front camera</title>
      <property key="state" type="string">floating</property>
      <property type="double" key="height">300</property>
      <property type="double" key="width">300</property>
      <property type="double" key="x">300</property>
      <property type="double" key="y">1</property>
      <property type="double" key="z">1</property>
    </ignition-gui>
  </plugin>
</gui>

<light name='sun' type='directional'>
  <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
  <pose>0 0 10 0 -0 0</pose>
  <diffuse>1 1 1 1</diffuse>
  <specular>0.5 0.5 0.5 1</specular>
  <attenuation>
    <range>1000</range>
    <constant>0.90000000000000002</constant>
    <linear>0.01</linear>
    <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
  </attenuation>
  <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
  <spot>
    <inner_angle>0</inner_angle>
    <outer_angle>0</outer_angle>
    <falloff>0</falloff>
  </spot>
  <visualize>false</visualize>
</light>
<gravity>0 0 0</gravity>
<magnetic_field>6e-06 2.3e-05 -4.2e-05</magnetic_field>
<atmosphere type='adiabatic'/>

<model name='auv'>
  <link name='base_link'>
  </link>

  <link name='front_depth_camera'>
    <pose>0.19 0.035 -0.08 0 0 1.57</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>1e-10</mass>
    </inertial>
    <visual name='front_depth_camera_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>0.01 0.01 0.01</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <sensor type="depth_camera" name="front_depth_camera">
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>2.00</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>320</width>
          <height>240</height>
          <format>R_FLOAT32</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.1</near>
          <far>10.0</far>
        </clip>
      </camera>
    </sensor>
  </link>

  <joint name='front_depth_camera_joint' type='fixed'>
    <parent>base_link</parent>
    <child>front_depth_camera</child>
  </joint>

  <link name='front_camera'>
    <pose>0.19 0.035 -0.08 0 0 1.57</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>1e-10</mass>
    </inertial>
    <visual name='front_camera_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>0.01 0.01 0.01</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <sensor type="camera" name="front_camera">
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>2.00</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>320</width>
          <height>240</height>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.1</near>
          <far>10.0</far>
        </clip>
      </camera>
    </sensor>
  </link>

  <joint name='front_camera_joint' type='fixed'>
    <parent>base_link</parent>
    <child>front_camera</child>
  </joint>
</model>

<model name='ref_model'>
  <link name='ref_link'>
    <pose>0 1 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <visual name='ref_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
</model>

<model name='ref_model2'>
  <link name='ref_link2'>
    <pose>-1 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <visual name='ref_visual2'>
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
</model>
```

---

Originally posted by [florian.pix](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/81881/florian.pix/) with karma: 11 on 2022-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2022-05-24**:
This is correct method to use. You actually can use 3 camera at the same time as well through ign topic. I use them through ros2 foxy to ign. GUI may be limited to one per sensor however you can just duplicate them. See here for example:
[image: image description]

But you can get them all at once through programming. See here:

`{'sensory_data': {'ir': {1: True, 0: True, 2: True},`
The name is changed to sensory_data.

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2022-05-24**:
So, the OP can just do his/her little art project then add the plugin like florian.pix mentioned.

Keep it in mind, you need to add a plugin per `link` (or model if you are too advanced already)

Your post is absolutely correct, IMO.

+1!